# DateTime suggestions with string format

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, datetime

I'm making a query which compares two `DateTime` values in SQL Server. The format of `DateTime` in SQL server is this:

```
 2010-09-20 00:00:00.000
```

I'm using Entity Framework and let me tell you the problem I'm facing now.

When I'm comparing a `DateTime` value in Entity Framework, the attribute must be the same as the database which means that must be `DateTime`. The date comes from a post and that means that is a string.  The problem here is, how can I convert them into `DateTime` and be the same format as it is in the database?

The user's input comes as a string and what I do is this:

```
DateTime start_date = Convert.ToDateTime(postValueHere);
```

But the value is not as expected:

```
2010/20/46 12:00:00 am
```

So, I give a format to it:

```
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000";
string date = start_date .ToString(format);
```

But now the value becomes as a string, which means that I cannot compare the value with Entity Framework:

```
db.Product.Where(x=>x.START_DATE== date)//error, cannot compare datetime with string.
```

How can I convert the user's input to the same format as it is in SQL Server and then to `DateTime`?

Comment: Why you compare values as strings, but not as dateTime?

Comment: 2010/20/46 12:00:00 am isn't a valid DateTime at all. What error do you get when you db.Product.Where(x=>x.START_DATE== Convert.ToDateTime(postValueHere)) ?

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime(postValueHere);` should get it into a C# `DateTime` object, and then Entity Framework should handle the conversion for you when you do `db.Product.Where(x=>x.START_DATE== date)`. Not really sure where the problem is.

Comment: @TimWagaman it i try what you say, the ouput will be 2010-02-11 12:00:00:00.000 and it will never be the same because the database does not have 12:00:00:00.000 anywhere, instead it has  2010-02-11 00:00:00.000

Comment: I mistakenly thought that `ParseExact` would be the solution. The problem is getting the string into a `DateTime` from what the user entered. Then you have two `DateTime` objects that will compare with each other fine, they have no concept of "format" as `DateTime` (only when you format them to a `string`). The only things to consider is the current locale and accepting user input in valid formats. If the value in SQL is also a valid `DateTime` data type, then again format won't matter, only locale (unless of course you store UTC).

Answer (score 2):

you can try with [DateTime.TryParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) as :

```
 DateTime start_date;
 DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt",
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out start_date);
 Console.WriteLine(start_date);
```

you can check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more custom formats.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EF to get that date value from the database, it should end up in a property with a DateTime type. This value is just a DateTime struct, *without any format*.
When you inspect the parsed date from the post, the debugger uses a `.ToString()` on the value, to get a string that it can display. It's still a DateTime struct without any format!

So just compare the DateTime values, without worrying about formats.